# Bash- is it possible to use -uniq for only one column of a line?

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

```
    1.gui  Qxx  16
    2.gu   Qxy  23
    3.guT  QWS  18
    4.gui  Qxr  21
```

i want to sort a file depending a value in the 3rd column, so i use:

```
sort -rnk3 myfile

2.gu   Qxy  23
4.gui  Qxr  21
3.guT  QWS  18
1.gui  Qxx  16
```

now i have to output as: (the line starting with 3.gui  is out because the line with 4.gui has a greater value)

```
2.gu   Qxy  23
4.gui  Qxr  21
1.guT  QWS  18
```

i can not use `-head` because i have millions of rows and i do not where to cut, i could not figure a way to use `-uniq` because it treats a line as whole and since i can not tell `-uniq` to look at first column, it counts a line which has  unique it outputs it -which is normal-. i know `-uniq` can ignore a number of characters but as you can see from example first column might have various character count..

please advice..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to 'uniq' by column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915636/is-there-a-way-to-uniq-by-column)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
sort -rnk3 myfile | awk -F"[. ]" '!a[$2]++'
```

awk removes the duplicates depending on the 2nd column.  This is actually a famous awk syntax to remove duplicates. An array is maintained where the record of 2nd field is maintained. Every time before a record is printed, the 2nd field is checked in the array. If not present, it is printed, else its discarded since it is duplicate. This is achived using the ++. First time, when a record is encountered, this ++ will keep the count as 0 since its post-fix. SUbsequent occurences will increase the value which when negated becomes false.

Comment: 2nd column because we are splitting the file with . and space as delimiter, and hence 2nd column will give us gui,etc..

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
sort -rnk3 file | awk -F'[. ]' '{ if (a[$2]++ == 0) print }' 

2.gu   Qxy  23
4.gui  Qxr  21
1.guT  QWS  18
```

This uses `awk` to check duplicate values in the second field where by the field separator is either a whitespace or a period. So this is what it treats the second field as:

```
$ awk -F'[. ]' '{ print $2 }' file

gu
gui
guT
gui
```

In `awk` the variable `$0` represents the whole line, `$1` represents the first field, and so on..

`awk -F'[. ]' '{ if (a[$2]++ == 0) print }'` the `-F` options let you specify the field separator, in this case it's either whitespace or a period.

Comment: hey @sudo_O ..thanks again. can you please explain the -awk command a litle?

Answer (score 0):

So I found this by the all powerful and amazing Google --
My little script builds off @sudo_O 's answer, in that it shows you all the duplicate lines found...., not a file without duplicates.

The text I was finding all duplicates in the 3rd column (port) were in a file called master.txt

```
awk '{if (a[$3]++ > 0) print}' master.txt | while read site thread port
do
  grep $port master.txt
done
```