# Sorting unique by column - sort command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sorting

I have this file:

```
hello 1
hello 2
world 1
world 2
hello 3
hi    3
hi    4
```

I want to sort this like so,

```
hello 1
hi  3
world 1
```

The thing is I need only the first unique item in column 1.

I tried `sort -k1 -u file.txt` but it isn't working as I expect. How do I go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to 'uniq' by column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915636/is-there-a-way-to-uniq-by-column)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sort -uk1,1 file
```

This sorts the file on the first field only and removes duplicate lines based on the first field.

Comment: Can you please explain this ?

Comment: `-k1` sorts from field 1 through the last field (if you had 5 columns, it's identical to `-k1,5`). `-k1,1` sorts on the first and only the first column.

Answer (score 8):

Sort and give unique list based on column 1

**sort -u -t : -k 1,1 test.txt**

-t : = colon is separator

-k 1,1 = based on column 1

Sort and give unique list based on column 1 & column 3

**sort -u -t : -k 1,1 -k 3,3 test.txt**

-t : = colon is separator

-k 1,1 3,3 = based on column 1 & column 3

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe it to awk:

```
sort -k1 file | awk '!($1 in a){a[$1]; print}'
hello 1
hi    3
world 1
```

Comment: Can you please explain above solution

Comment: awk command checks `$1` exists in array `a`. If it doesn't exist it prints whole line and stuffs `$1` in array `a`.

Comment: Why sort -k1 -u file.txt doesnt work? Basically here itself we are sorting and removing duplicates based on first column right?

Comment: `-k1,1` means start and end at position 1.