# how can I delete duplicates in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I have a SQLite DB where the statement:

```
SELECT messdatum, count(*) as anzahl 
from lipo 
GROUP BY Messdatum 
ORDER BY anzahl desc;
```

results in some lines, which indicates that I have some duplicates with the same `Messdatum`.
How can I delete the duplicates only form my sqlite db? (it should delete anzahl-1 records where the messdatum is the same?) Has anyone an advice?

PS: I found this link [How to remove duplicate from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444/de) but have problems with sqlite dialect. I got some errors due to the sqlite syntax.
So f.e. I could do:

```
 INSERT into holdkey SELECT messdatum, count(*) as anzahl from lipo group by messdatum having count(*) > 1;

 INSERT into holddups SELECT DISTINCT lipo.* from lipo, holdkey where lipo.Messdatum = holdkey.messdatum ;

 DELETE lipo from lipo, holdkey where lipo.messdatum = holdkey.messdatum;
```

here is an error at the  delete command.  How can I do that? I tried to update the holdkey.anzahl to an additional col in lipo with

```
UPDATE lipo,holdkey set lipo.duplettenzahl = holdkey.anzahl WHERE lipo.messdatum = holdkey.messdatum ;
```

but this is also not possible. If I would have the anzahl as dublettenzahl in lipo I could delete all records from lipo where dublettenzahl > 0. Please help! Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting duplicate rows from sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8190541/608639)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

SQLite has a [special column, `ROWID`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) created on every table by default (you can [switch it off](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) using the `WITHOUT ROWID` modifier, but be very sure before doing so).

This means that we can identify specific rows within sets of duplicates, for example, finding the first entry for a value:

```
SELECT messdatum, MIN(ROWID) FROM lipo
```

So one way to remove duplicates might be this:

```
DELETE FROM lipo
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(rowid) 
  FROM lipo 
  GROUP BY messdatum
)
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason not to use the usual primary key field such as `id` (if present) instead of `ROWID`?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution:

```
 INSERT into holdkey SELECT messdatum, count(*) as anzahl,NameISO from lipo group by messdatum having count(*) > 1;
 INSERT into holddups SELECT DISTINCT lipo.*,1 from lipo, holdkey where lipo.Messdatum = holdkey.messdatum group by messdatum;
 INSERT into lipo_mit_dz  SELECT *, count(*) as DublettenZahl from lipo group by messdatum ORDER BY Dublettenzahl desc ;
 DELETE from lipo_mit_dz where Dublettenzahl > 1;
 INSERT into lipo_mit_dz SELECT * from holddups ;
```