# make sure cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, spinner

Can anyone help me how to execute this query?

I am trying to fetch distinct supervisor from project table. supervisor is column name and its index is 5.

```
try {

String query = "select distinct supervisor from project ";
            Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(query,null);//query( query , null, null,null,null,null,null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    labels.add(cursor.getString(5));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

           // finish();
           cursor.close();
           db.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return labels;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Post your table implementation

Comment: Project is name of table and supervisor is column name.. I want all distinct supervisor but I am getting error... can you please help me to execute this distinct query ?

Comment: see my updated answer. It will give you what you expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong.

You have to query write like this.

```
select * from project where YOUR_CONDITION
```

I don't know what you exactly trying to do.

Example query.

```
select * from customers where LastName = 'Tremblay'
```

To get Distinct value of supervisor you should query like this.

```
select * from project group by supervisor
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: then just try `select * from project`

Comment: select * from project is working fine but i need only distinct names from database one name is repeating many times

Comment: we can't execute distinct query without condition ?

Comment: Simple, use `select distinct supervisor from project`

Comment: its not working i am trying this .. getting error "make sure cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

 "

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884095/how-can-i-delete-duplicates-in-sqlite this will help you to delete duplicate from database

Comment: Mark it as correct answer if it works for you. It will help others.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an if statement ie if cursor != null, do something.