# Decipher different columns in bash file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cut

I have a file that is in the following format:

```
6,test,A,B,C,D
6,test,A,B,C,F
7,test,A,B,C
7,test,A,B,D
```

I would like to write something that outputs the different columns. For example:

```
6 - column 6 is different
7 - column 5 is different
```

Columns will always be separated by a comma and the first column will always be the unique identifier among the rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to 'uniq' by column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915636/is-there-a-way-to-uniq-by-column)

Comment: This is NOT what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

here is the prototype that works, fix the text for your needs

```
$ awk -F, '$1 in a{n=split(a[$1],p);
                   for(i=2;i<=n;i++) 
                       if(p[i]!=$i) print $1,i " different"; next}
                  {a[$1]=$0}' file

6 6 different
7 5 different
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.