# Count unique value from awk output

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I want to know how many user have visited google.com using my proxy with last 30 minutes.

```
 awk -v bt=$(date "+%s" -d "30 minutes ago") '($1 > bt) && $4~/google.com/ {printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n", strftime("%F %T",$1), $2 , $3, $4)} ' access.log
```

The logs look like this

```
2017-02-19 12:09:44|test@gmail.com|200|https://google.com/
2017-02-19 12:10:23|test@gmail.com|200|https://google.com/
```

Now i can easily count the number of records

```
 awk -v bt=$(date "+%s" -d "30 minutes ago") '($1 > bt) && $4~/google.com/ {printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n", strftime("%F %T",$1), $2 , $3, $4)} ' access.log | wc -l
```

Output is 2.

How can i modify the command to display only records with unique email.In the above case the output should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list result

```
awk -v FS='|' -v bt="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d '30 minutes ago')" '
    ($1 > bt) && $4~/google.com/  && !seen[$2]++
  ' access.log
```

To get count

```
awk -v FS='|' -v bt="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d '30 minutes ago')" '
    ($1 > bt) && $4~/google.com/  && !seen[$2]++{ count++ }
    END{ print count+0 }
  ' access.log
```

**For Testing**

```
# Current datetime of my system
$ date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2017-02-26 00:06:19

# 30 minutes ago what was datetime
$ date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d '30 minutes ago'
2017-02-25 23:36:20

# Input file, I modified datetime to check command
$ cat f
2017-02-25 23:10:44|test@gmail.com|200|https://google.com/
2017-02-25 23:45:23|test@gmail.com|200|https://google.com/
```

**Output - 1 to see result**

```
$ awk -v FS='|' -v bt="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d '30 minutes ago')" '
    ($1 > bt) && $4~/google.com/  && !seen[$2]++
  ' f
2017-02-25 23:45:23|test@gmail.com|200|https://google.com/
```

**Output - 2 to see count**

```
$ awk -v FS='|' -v bt="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d '30 minutes ago')" '
    ($1 > bt) && $4~/google.com/  && !seen[$2]++{ count++ }
    END{ print count+0 }
  ' f
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` to select unique email account.

And you can refer to [is-there-a-way-to-uniq-by-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915636/is-there-a-way-to-uniq-by-column)

Answer (score 0):

Simply pipe the logs to

```
sort -u -t "|" -k "2"
```

So you will have something like:

```
awk -v bt=$(date "+%s" -d "30 minutes ago") '($1 > bt) && $4~/google.com/ {printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n", strftime("%F %T",$1), $2 , $3, $4)} ' access.log | sort -u -t "|" -k "2"
```