# csv remove all rows with duplicate values in one column

Tags: linux, shell, csv

example1.csv

```
id1, value1
id2, value2
id3, value3
id1, value4
```

example2.csv

```
"06e04,0428","405872,8637110"
"06e04,0428","405872,8637111"
"06e04,0429","405872,8637110"
"06e04,0430","405872,8637110"
"06e04,0431","405872,8637111"
```

Need to remove rows with duplicate values in column1, with output as below

**required output**

example1_out.csv

```
id2, value2
id3, value3
```

example2_out.csv

```
"06e04,0429","405872,8637110"
"06e04,0430","405872,8637110"
"06e04,0431","405872,8637111"
```

there are solutions to remove duplicate records which retain one of the duplicate records as in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1915636). However in this case all the rows with duplicate values for column1 need to excluded from the output.

Comment: You've tagged your question `shell`. Do you mean `bash`?

Comment: @Grzesiek - could you pls add the nodejs answer ?

Comment: @user3206440  I am sorry The selected solution with the use of awk is shorter.

Comment: @ghoti - yes I mean bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` can do that in a single command:

```
awk -F, '{arr[$1]=$0} seen[$1]++{delete arr[$1]} END{for (i in arr) print arr[i]}' file.csv

id2, value2
id3, value3
```

---

For your edited question use:

```
awk -F'","' '{arr[$1]=$0} seen[$1]++{delete arr[$1]} END{for (i in arr) print arr[i]}' file.csv

"06e04,0429","405872,8637110"
"06e04,0430","405872,8637110"
"06e04,0431","405872,8637111"
```

Comment: Note that this does not preserve line order `id3, value3 id2, value2`

Comment: this doesn't work well when column 1 has values with `,` - see updated question.

Comment: I've modified my answer based on your edited question. Check updated answer which is giving expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -f1 -d, somecsv.csv | sort | uniq -u | grep -Ff- somecsv.csv
```

The first command extracts the first column from the input. The second command sorts the ids, so the next command can only list the unique ones. The final `grep` takes the unique ids and searches for them in the input file.

Comment: Hm... this will also match the lines, where the text in col1 is contained in the other colums... e.g. `id1, valid2`

Comment: So change `grep -Ff-` to `sed 's/^/^/' | grep -f-`. Again, it can break if the first column contains special characters...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter awk option.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} a[$1]<2' file.csv file.csv
```

This reads the file twice -- once to populate an array of counters of the first field, and the second time to print lines whose count is less than 2.

If you'd prefer to do this in pure shell rather than awk, and your shell is `bash`, you could get similar functionality with something like this:

```
$ declare -A a=()
$ while IFS=, read f _; do ((a[$f]++)); done < file.csv
$ declare -p a
declare -A a=([id1]="2" [id3]="1" [id2]="1" )
$ while IFS=, read f1 f2; do [ "${a[$f1]}" -lt 2 ] && printf '%s,%s\n' "$f1" "$f2"; done < file.csv
id2, value2
id3, value3
```

Again, this is two steps -- the first to populate an array of counters, the second to step through the file and print appropriate lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` :

```
awk -F  "," '{
    if (length(arr[$1]) == 0){
        arr[$1]=$0
        order[i++]=$1
    }
    else{
        delete arr[$1]
    }
}
 END { 
    for (i = 1; i < length(order); i++) { 
        print arr[order[i]]
    } 
}' somecsv.csv
```

It stores all entries in an array and remove the item if it's found twice. The order is preserved with an additional `order` array