# Uniq a column and print out number of rows in that column

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file, with header

```
name, age, id, address 
Smith, 18, 201392, 19 Rand Street, USA
Dan, 19, 029123, 23 Lambert Rd, Australia
Smith, 20, 192837, 61 Apple Rd, UK
Kyle, 25, 245123, 103 Orange Rd, UK
```

And I'd like to sort out duplicates on names, so the result will be:

```
Smith, 18, 201392, 19 Rand Street, USA
Dan, 19, 029123, 23 Lambert Rd, Australia
Kyle, 25, 245123, 103 Orange Rd, UK

# prints 3 for 3  unique rows at column name
```

I've tried `sort -u -t, -k1,1 file`, `awk -F"," '!_[$1]++' file` but it doesn't work because I have commas in my address.

Comment: So only the first occurrence of name is on result file ? What about `Kyle` ?

Comment: @Niloct yup. Edited,  sorry! missed that out

Comment: Try awk -F, 'NR==1||seen[$1]{next}{seen[$1]++}1' file

Comment: `awk -F"," '!_[$1]++' file` works, you will have to discard first output line if you don't need the header on output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to 'uniq' by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915636/is-there-a-way-to-uniq-by-column)

Comment: `awk -F"," '!_[$1]++' data | sed "1 d"`, assuming your file is named `data`.

Comment: @Niloct they both work, however is it possible to only have the "name" column printed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you changed the functionality since the OP, but this should get you unique names in your file (considering it's named `data`), unsorted:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed "1 d" data | awk -F"," '!_[$1]++ { print $1 }'
```

If you need to sort, append `| sort` to the command line above.

And append `| wc -l` to the command line to count lines.

Comment: I passed a ```wc -l``` to count the number of unique names, but it returns 11 when the actual number is 10. Why do you think that's happening?

Comment: Are there empty newlines in the data file ? Probably you have the last line with a linebreak and no content.

Comment: Right. Thank you so much :)