# How to unique by column large file via sort command?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, awk, unique

i have large list (6 million lines) and want to sort unique by column #2, how to do it by sort command?
In example

```
CONT,000-00-0000,GRAM
BEVE,507-66-6876,IGHT
MICH,000-00-0000,EVINS
CONT,111-11-1111,GRAM
```

trasnfer to

```
CONT,000-00-0000,GRAM
BEVE,507-66-6876,IGHT
CONT,111-11-1111,GRAM
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to 'uniq' by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915636/is-there-a-way-to-uniq-by-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '!array[$2]++' input_file
CONT,000-00-0000,GRAM
BEVE,507-66-6876,IGHT
CONT,111-11-1111,GRAM
```